# how to display blobs with areas greater than 1000

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

i have a stack of dicom images, i have applied thresholding and obtain binary images ,after labeling the binary images and i got areas 50, 150, 450, 851, 1053,22301 , now my question is how to display blobs with areas greater then 1000.

```
mri %stack of dicom images 
im = squeeze(mri(:,:,14));
max_level = double(max(im(:)));
min_level = double(min(im(:)));
levels = graythresh(double(im)/min_level) * max_level;
bw = (mri>=levels);
%imshow(bw(:,:,14))
L = bwlabeln(bw);
stats = regionprops(L,'Area','Centroid');
A = [stats.Area]
L(A>1000 & A<24100) =1;
mri(L ~= L(1) )=0;
K = imadjust(mri(:,:,15));
imshow(K)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [bwareaopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) it will mask blobs that are smaller than an given threshold

```
minimum_blob_size = 1000;
bw_without_small_blobs = bwareaopen(bw, minimum_blob_size);
imshow(bw_without_small_blobs );
```

**EDIT**

if you want to use this new binary image as a mask something like this should work

```erlang
%this code is a little complex, but it multiplies the mask by the image
%the nice part is this will even work for an RGB (multi-channel) image
%as well as gray scale
masked_im = bsxfun(@times, im, cast(bw_without_small_blobs,class(im)));

imshow(masked_im);
```

Comment: i have used bwareaopen, for one blob it works fine but when multiple blobs are selected to be displayed matlab gives error matrix dimension must agree.

Comment: I had the variable names wrong, you should have been using `bw` not `K` i fixed the error. It should run now

Comment: sir i have got two blobs in binary image using bwareaopen, i want to display it now in grayscale because visualization can not be done with binary mri(L ~= bw_without_small_blobs )=0

Comment: See my edit. I used the mask from `bwareaopen` on the original image, I think this is what you want.